# Distinguishing between nothing and A=>Any for overloaded methods

Tags: scala

I'm not sure if I choose a good title for this question.

Suppose the following code:

```
object Test {
  def f1[A](p1: A => Int) = println("f1")
  def f1[A](p1: A => Int, p2: A => Int) = println("f2")
}
```

Executing `Test.f1[String](_.toInt)` returns the following error:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toInt)
              Test.f1[String](_.toInt)
                              ^
```

But `Test.f1[String]((a: String) => a.toInt)` will execute without error.
If I removed the second `f1` method from `Test` object the code will also execute.

It seems that Scala needs to know about the parameter types before it decide about the overloaded methods. it can't distinguish between nothing and `A => Int` in this situation. If true, why?

Are there any alternatives for such situations?

Comment: not an answer, but i the passing version '(a: String) => ...', you don't need to be explicit in the  '[String]' type parameter, which mitigates the problem

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't use Hindley-Milner type inference. Scala is built on the jvm which uses type erasure: the class exists on runtime but its parameter types doesn't. If you want to eliminate the disadvantages a little bit, read this: [Making the most of Scala's (extremely limited) type inference](http://pchiusano.blogspot.hu/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html)